# Why does the if statement act like this?

Tags: swift, if-statement

Let's say I have an array of MyObject that contains only one MyObject that is different from the object passed as parameter in the contains function.

I would like to understand why, when I write my code like this, it's works, I don't go to the line `myObject.toAdd = true`

```
if self.myObjectArray != nil && contains(self.myObjectArray!, myObject) == true {
    myObject.toAdd = true
}
```

but when I don't write `== true` it goes straight inside my if statement while it shouldn't (from my point of view and what I want to do at least...)

```
if self.myObjectArray != nil && contains(self.myObjectArray!, myObject) {
    myObject.toAdd = true
}
```

What's the difference?

Thanks for your help

Comment: you are not comparing anything on this part `contains(self.myObjectArray!, myObject)`

Comment: but when I do just **if contains(self.myObjectArray!, myObject)** it works as expected. I guess then when there are two or more predicates in an if statement, you need to compare them explicitly to something ... Am I right? Thanks @Ethaan

Comment: hmm and if you put `if self.myObjectArray != nil` it returns true right?

Comment: You should _never_ compare a Bool to `true` or `false` in a condition. Its use in a condition _is_ testing its truth value.

Comment: @Ethaan yes it returns true.

Comment: Is this your exact code? Those two `if` statements are saying the same thing.

Comment: yes it is my exact code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if self.myObjectArray != nil && contains(self.myObjectArray!, myObject) == true {
    myObject.toAdd = true
}
```

Your goal here, I see, is to unwrap the Optional `self.myObjectArray` and use it in a `contains` call only if it is safe to do so. This is not a direct answer to your question, but it is much better Swift Optional-handling practice to unwrap in a conditional binding first:

```
if let arr = self.myObjectArray {
    if contains(arr, myObject) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The result is clearer. Personally, I also like the resulting nesting; in Swift 1.2 there may be ways around the nesting, even, but I don't regard it as something to be avoided.

Also, returning to your original question, comparison of a Bool to `true` or `false` in a condition is just silly (and perhaps not entirely predictable?). The condition is *already* evaluating the Bool for its truth-value; that's what a condition *is*.

Comment: Yes I'm not used to optional bindings yet. Thanks